# auto annotating types in typescript / VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

The rust analyzer in VS Code generates type annotations by linting. This looks like the following picture where the grey annotation is added automatically according to context.

[image: inline type annotations by rust-analyzer]

Is there any known way (Extension) to acieve this behavior using other typed languages like typescript or (typed) python? Since the types are known from context, as shown by hovering over the variables, such a behavior should not be that hard to realise?

[image: typescript type hints by hovering]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [inlay hints](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-editing#_inlay-hints) configuration options (on the namespaces `"typescript.inlayHints"` and `"javascript.inlayHints"` respectively).

---

For example:

Given a workspace with a TypeScript file such as this one:

`./example.ts`:

```ts
const keys = Object.keys({});
```

and using the default configuration:

`./.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
{}
```

the TS file will look like this:

[image: inlay hints disabled]

But after enabling the inlay hints setting for variable types:

`./.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
{
  "typescript.inlayHints.variableTypes.enabled": true
}
```

the file will look like this:

[image: inlay hints enabled]